# User Status Dependency in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I am not sure below scenario can be implemented in Jira or not.

In current workflow we have 16 status.

Say Status 1, Status 2, Status 3.... Status 16

Now Status 1 to Status 4 Will be with Team A's X Person.

Once Task/Issue Move to Status 5 then It will be with Team B's Person Y.

and So on..

We have n number of Team which is dependent on Each other

Above System is developed outside the JIRA and now we are planning to migrate to JIRA.

So Now In JIRA I am not sure about Below Points.

1. How to plan Working Hours in in JIRA for above Scenario?
2. If Person X is on Leave for the day , Will All Task(s)/Issue(s) Automatically Shifted to next Working day? OR We need to manage it manually?
3. How to manage Multiple team's Estimation for single task?
4. Is that possible to add user ownership Relevant to status ? say Status 1 to 4 Will Be managed By X Team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:

> How to plan Working Hours in in JIRA for above Scenario?

One method could be to have subtasks. Create one bigger enclosing task that have a subtask that refers to status from 1 to 4, then another subtask with status from 5 to 10 and so on. Each subtask type will have its own workflow if necessary and also could be planned independiently.

> If Person X is on Leave for the day , Will All Task(s)/Issue(s)
>   Automatically Shifted to next Working day? OR We need to manage it
>   manually?

Not sure if I understand this one. Vanilla Jira won't do anything if a person is out for a day. Working hours in Jira doesn't count if a person is in it or not just the hours the person says that they are working in it (by filling a work log).

> How to manage Multiple team's Estimation for single task?

If several persons estimates a single task then someone should be the one to decide what estimation is the most accurate one. You could use some other tool like Confluence to make a collaborative estimation of tasks and once a decission is made create the task in Jira (You can create task in Jira directly from Confluence)

> Is that possible to add user ownership Relevant to status ? say Status
>   1 to 4 Will Be managed By X Team?

You can have postfunctions (Jira's defaults and third party ones via Atlassian Marketplace) that can make things (like making someone the task assignee) depending on the transition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, have you used [link](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212136/portfolio-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) or any other add-on which have Task Estimation/Leave management ?

Comment: @SmitShah No, I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning multiple teams working on a single issue with 16 statuses:

See [Jira Agile](https://www.atlassian.com/agile), assuming using *Atlassian Software* server.

Jira works better with *multiple* projects, **one team per project**.

```
                                              TeamA          TeamB         TeamC ...
Feature parent                                Story          Story
DO-11 Do Foo  -> children ---------------->   TA-23 Bar A    TB-34 Bar B
                                                ^----------- depends on
```

Estimate story points for the children, not the parent. That solves the estimate.

DO-11 Do Foo (parent)

- TA-23 Bar A  - Story points: 8
- TB-34 Bar B (depends on TA-23) - Story points: 5
- TC-30 Bar C (depends on TB-34) - Story points: 3

Create a *Sprint* and add the stories to it.  The sprint will total up the story points.  You can manually adjust for time off by reducing how many story points you commit to.

Add the Feature and Stories to an **Epic** to tie it all together visually (the epic is displayed in the story summary).

```
Sprint 1  
  DO-11 Do Foo                                 Epic Foo  
  TA-23 Bar A                                  Epic Foo   8
  TB-34 Bar B                                  Epic Foo   5
  TB-30 Bar C                                  Epic Foo   3
                                    Story point estimate 16
```

In summary, the parent Feature tracks the overall task (update status as children are completed), estimates are for the child stories, and the children form a chain of dependencies for the workflow.